# Functionality of views.py and urls.py in django?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie in djnago. I am trying to understand the openstack project. In one place they are calling class `AdminIndexView` through url in `urls.py`. I understand how the url works, but in `class AdminIndexView` there are some methods like `def get_data(self):`, `def has_more_data`. I wanted to know where they call these methods. And in `urls.py` they are using something like `url(r'^$', views.AdminIndexView.as_view(), name='index')`. What do `as_view` and `name='index'` mean?

**views.py**

```
class AdminIndexView(tables.DataTableView):
    table_class = project_tables.AdminInstancesTable
    template_name = 'admin/instances/index.html'
    page_title = _("Instances")

    def has_more_data(self, table):
        return self._more

    def get_data(self):
        instances = []
        marker = self.request.GET.get(
            project_tables.AdminInstancesTable._meta.pagination_param, None)
        search_opts = self.get_filters({'marker': marker, 'paginate': True})
        # Gather our tenants to correlate against IDs
        try:
            tenants, has_more = api.keystone.tenant_list(self.request)
        except Exception:
            tenants = []
            msg = _('Unable to retrieve instance project information.')
            exceptions.handle(self.request, msg)

        if 'project' in search_opts:
            ten_filter_ids = [t.id for t in tenants
                              if t.name == search_opts['project']]
            del search_opts['project']
            if len(ten_filter_ids) > 0:
                search_opts['tenant_id'] = ten_filter_ids[0]
            else:
                self._more = False
                return []
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url

from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin.instances import views
INSTANCES = r'^(?P<instance_id>[^/]+)/%s$'
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'openstack_dashboard.dashboards.admin.instances.views',
    url(r'^$', views.AdminIndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Comment: >>> There are lots of tutorial on internet but it will take much time !

Comment: The tutorials and documentation are out there for this reason, for you to read them and learn! Here is the documentation for [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/) which is what you are asking about in `as_view()`.

Comment: @sobolevn Sorry, I want to just understand these topic.

Comment: You may want to look for [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/).

Answer (score 0):

In Django you can hook up URL patterns to a handler. These handlers are either functions are can be "class based". In short class based views are good! and .as_view() basically sets up the class to accept requests from a URL pattern. 
I suggest you look here for more info on class based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/.

The name parameter is an arbitrary name you can give to a URL so that you can find it later, for example you if you needed to construct the URL of a certain view instead of creating the url yourself each time, you would call a method.

```
reverse("<app_name>:<name>")
```

Where app_name is the name of your application and name is the value in the name parameter (in Django 1.8 + names of urls are name spaced by app_name)

As for the get_data methods, these are called by the superclass of your view see here for more info on that: 
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/topics/tables.html#fetching-the-row-data